# Can I load data to option.html from execution of content-script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My content-script grabs some data from current page and after that I need to give user an ability to select some categories from the NOT predifined list (means, it depends upon content of page where my extension runs). Is there a way to transfer this data to my options.html page? If no, what is the best way to implement described functionality?

Comment: You need to explain the expected flow better. An options page is a separate page; when you open it, what is "page where my extension runs"? Can there only be one at a time? Is it activated by the user? What opens the options page? Please include a step by step scenario.

Comment: my 1) content-script might realize, that he needs some additional options, 2) so he gonna ask my background script to run `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()` method and show my `options.html` page, which is defined in my manifes. The content of 'options.html' must depend upon what my content-script wants to show to the user: it is always a list of some categories (like 'electronics', 'books', 'computers'), but concrete content IS NOT predefined: once again, it depend on content-script execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can make use of [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Simply store the data you want when the content script runs and you will be able to access this data from your options page using the same APIs.